# Qual o DPI recomendado para imagens utilizadas em websites?

Tags: imagem, webdesign, dpi

Sempre utilizei 72 dpi nas minhas imagens, mas atualmente este padrão vem apresentando baixa definição graças a variedade de dispositivos com resoluções diferentes (notebook, tablet, smartphones e etc). Qual seria o DPI recomendado para ser utilizado nos dias de hoje?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Resposta rápida:

Tanto faz :)

### Calma, tem explicação!

DPI significa "Dots per Inch", ou "Pontos por polegada". No arquivo digital, esta informação é um mero número armazenado nos metadados.

O conteúdo da imagem em si são os pixels. Quanto mais pixel, mais definição. o *dpi* é um "aviso" para o programa de saída, dizendo "faça esses pixels caberem nesse espaço".

Na mídia impressa geralmente temos uma quantidade de pontos muito maior do que é necessário para a resolução do olho humano, e as impressoras comuns de mercado atualmente costumam ter saída de mais de 600 dpi, e geralmente o material enviado para as mesmas não precisa ser preparado com tanto detalhamento.

Entretanto, pela mesma razão, esta medida não faz sentido para telas. A tela é medida em pixels, e uma imagem 100x100 pixels @ 72 *dpi* aparece do mesmíssimo tamanho que uma imagem 100x100 pixels @ 9000 *dpi*, quando vista na tela, pois essa informação é ignorada. Afinal, na tela a intenção é usar todos os *pixels* disponíveis, pois usualmente o olho consegue discernir cada um deles individualmente.

Tanto que muitos formatos de imagem normalmente não armazenam nativamente a informação de *dpi*, como o Jpeg, por exemplo.

O problema do design adequado em várias "resoluções de tela" (entre aspas, pois na verdade resolução é um termo ambíguo para explicar a quantidade de pontos do dispositivo) está no tamanho efetivo da imagem **em pixels**.

### Exemplo prático:

Imagine uma imagem 300x300 px @ 300 *dpi*. Se tem 300 pontos por polegada, e a largura dessa imagem é 300 pixels (que equivale ao ponto, em imagens digitais), essa imagem ao ser impressa (sem que se edite a mesma, ou que se escale ela no programa de saída) teria uma polegada de largura e uma de altura.

Agora, imagine se as saídas em tela fossem respeitar o valor em *dpi*: Você faz uma imagem dessas e joga na tela, e ela aparece como um quadrado de uma polegada, aí joga na tela do celular e ela continua com uma polegada de largura e uma de altura... Ou pior! Imagine você apresentando a mesma imagem num projetor, para uma platéia. Ela teria que continuar aparecendo na medida de 1x1 polegada para manter os 300dpi. Provavelmente não é o resultado desejado.

Em suma: quando você muda o tamanho de um arquivo composto por pixels, o *dpi* passa a ser o resultado da quantidade de pontos final x a área efetiva ocupada, **e não o que está indicado no arquivo**.

É o que acontece na tela (ainda bem!): o *dpi* 'verdadeiro' da imagem é o do dispositivo. Da imagem original o que conta são os pixels.

### Solução:

Se você quer fazer um site ou app que aproveite bem tanto um celular com 800x480 pixels e um notebook desses novos com tela de 3200x1800 pixels, um caminho é usar imagens vetoriais, como SVG, que são escalonáveis sem perda de qualidade, ou o que é mais  tradicional, que é salvar várias imagens de tamanhos diferentes, e usá-las de acordo com o tamanho da tela.

No caso de múltiplas imagens, você pode recorrer ao **[media-query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)** do CSS, que permite que você especifique os atributos de acordo com a área disponível na tela, entre outras coisas.

Exemplo de *media-query*:

```css
#cabecalho {background: url(/imagem_grande.png) left center no-repeat}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
   #cabecalho {background: url(/imagem_media.png) left center no-repeat}
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
   #cabecalho {background: url(/imagem_pequena.png) left center no-repeat}
}
```

Ou seja, o elemento de ID `#cabecalho` vai exibir a `imagem_grande.png`, mas se a largura da área exibida for menor que 800px, o estilo será sobreescrito pelo do media-query inicial e o elemento exibirá a `imagem_media.png`, e mais que isso, no caso de telas de largura até 480px, a imagem será a `imagem_pequena.png`.

Este exemplo foi extremamente simplificado, lembre-se que com *media-queries* você pode mudar completamente o layout da página, não apenas o tamanho das imagens. O que vai dentro do *media-query* é CSS convencional, então podem ser mudadas cores, os alinhamentos e o que mais você imaginar.

> Lembre-se de definir um `@media print` caso use vários media queries e queira controlar o aspecto da versão impressa separadamente.

### <strike>E ainda sem solução definitiva:</strike>

<strike>Para os novos displays em alta resolução, ainda há uma discussão em andamento, pois por questões de compatibilidade, o WebKit, por exemplo, trata cada pixel como um conjunto de 4 pixels, 2x2, quando se trata de displays "Retina". Solução similar a essa é o que acontece com aplicações que usam "ampliação de dpi" no Windows.</strike>

<strike>O proposto pelo próprio pessoal do webkit.org é usar SVG para resolver o problema da ampliação ficar "feia", mas onde não for possível, há o *reparo técnico* <sup>1</sup>, que é usar imagens com o dobro de pixels escalonadas para baixo, como *CSS background*, possivelmente combinadas com um dos filtros do *media-query* que é o `min-device-ratio`. O problema é que isto é uma solução específica do WebKit, aparentemente não muito sólida. Resta saber o quanto é efetiva em outros navegadores.</strike>

Mais detalhes podem ser vistos [neste artigo](https://www.webkit.org/blog/55/high-dpi-web-sites/) <sup>(en)</sup>.

> **Update:** uma luz no fim do túnel, vinda do W3C (tomara que não seja um trem):
>   ["O atributo SRCSET - Uma extensão HTML para imagens adaptativas"](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/srcset/w3c-srcset/) <sup>(en)</sup>

> **Update2 (2017):** finalmente houve adoção do `srcset`:
>   [Como trocar a imagem em telas menores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/244294/70) (aqui no SOpt)

<sub>1. gambiarra</sub>

Comment: Aos amigos de Portugal, "tanto faz" tem o mesmo sentido aí? Aqui tem o sentido de "pouco importa", ou "qualquer coisa". Se aí for diferente, edito a resposta para ficar melhor.

Comment: Bacco, eu discordo do "tanto faz" e não achei sua resposta satisfatória. Quanto menos pixel por polegada, menor a definição da imagem. Um website com 72dpi visto no "Macbook Pro Retina" fica evidente a qualidade ruim das imagens . 72dpi é um padrão utilizado a muito tempo, e hoje não parece fazer sentido visto a qualidade das telas atuais.

Comment: @PauloMaciel, é melhor você dar mais detalhes sobre seus conhecimentos na própria pergunta. Agora mesmo, você diz "vem apresentando baixa definição", mas não provê nenhuma prova ou argumento.

Comment: @PauloMaciel infelizmente nem tudo que é fato é satisfatório, mas é assim que funciona. Não depende da minha vontade. De qualquer forma, faça testes, experimente, e no fim você perceberá que o que está faltando é pixel (e que ampliar imagem na tela sem ter pixels pra isso é sempre ruim).

Comment: @brasofilo, eu desenhei um circulo com preenchimento branco em um background transparente e exportei em png. Ao adicionar esta imagem no website em cima de uma cor verde, o circulo ficou com um perceptível serrilhado. Após alterar o DPI e exportar novamente em png com background transparente, o circulo perdeu o serrilhado. O fato de ter acontecido isso me gerou essa questão.

Comment: @PauloMaciel você viu se os dois tem a mesma quantidade de pixels?

Comment: Ambas imagens tinham o mesmo tamanho, mas isso só aconteceu com background transparente.

Comment: @PauloMaciel então o problema é outro. Poste as imagens e o html no exemplo, aí facilita pra gente avaliar (ou mesmo um link aqui nos comments, aí dá pra tentar ajudar melhor).

Comment: (lembrando que se o html não estiver com tudo em ordem, incluso o device-scaling o mac vai ampliar o site todo e detonar a imagem)

Comment: Eu acredito que esteja tudo certo, mas assim que eu puder eu retorno aqui e publico o html, css e imagem.

Comment: @PauloMaciel Nao esqueça disso no <head>: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> pro browser não ampliar por conta própria as imagens.

Comment: Meu head já utiliza essa meta tag, acredito ainda que era um problema na imagem.

Comment: @PauloMaciel depois espie esse artigo também, que deve ter relação com o problema: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SupportingHighdpiPixeldenseRetinaDisplaysLikeIPhonesOrTheIPad3WithCSSOrIMG.aspx (e o improviso com background image pra contornar)

Comment: @Bacco vou ler esse artigo, obrigado por ajudar