# É recomendado utilizar a unidade "em" ao invés de "px" para fontes?

Tags: css

Vejo que alguns sites ao definir o `font-size` utilizam a unidade `em`, em uma breve pesquisa eu li que é recomendado usar `em` em fontes por ser melhor do que a unidade `px`.

Afinal, qual seria a unidade certa ao definir o tamanho da fonte e por que?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Na verdade, não "é recomendado utilizar a unidade “em” ao invés de “px” para fontes". O fundamental é entender como funciona cada medida, para saber em que casos se aplica.

Tem casos em que o `em` é mais interessante, tem casos em que o `px` é mais interessante, e o mesmo para cada uma das medidas. Até o momento, aparentemente nenhuma delas é conflitante no sentido de deixar a outra obsoleta.

Se pensar em uma página com layou estático, uma vez definidas as medidas, elas só vão variar se houver alguma variação no cliente que for "renderizar" a página, mas sempre aparecerão da mesma forma no mesmo navegador, em princípio.

Se pensar numa página com layout dinâmico, que se adapta à largura da tela (superficialmente apelidado de "layout responsivo", termo que por sinal, não tem um significado objetivo), e/ou onde o tamanho das fontes pode ser especificado diferentemente dependendo das quebras especificadas com `@media` ou JS, o uso de cada uma delas pode ter um efeito mais radical.

Neste caso, se você quer os espaços e medidas sempre "fixos" em relação às imagens e aos device-pixels, provavelmente vai usar `px`. Se quiser que os espaços acompanhem a ampliação ou redução da fonte em cada medida, vai usar `em` ou `rem`, e talvez `%` em certos contextos.

Estas não são regras, são exemplificações. Para saber a adequada para seu caso, precisa entender as diferenças:

### O "em":

O `em` **reflete** a medida da fonte corrente em pixels. É melhor do que `px`? Não, na verdade é um complemento.

O que vale mesmo é saber qual usar no caso concreto. Estas unidades de medidas existem para serem usadas conforme são necessarias.

Um exemplo de uso:

```
.exemplo {
   font-size: 20px;
   border-radius: .5em;
   padding-bottom: 2em;
}
```

Neste caso, a curva da borda terá 10px, e o `padding-bottom` 40px.

Vantagem? Neste caso, basta mudar o tamanho da fonte, que o resto dos elementos vai acompanhar proporcionalmente.

Um outro exemplo:

```
.exemplo {
   font-size: 20px;
   line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

Assim, teremos espaçamento 1,5 entre linhas.

Nas versões mais velhas do IE só conseguíamos ampliar as fontes se elas fossem especificadas em `em`s ou com `<font size=`.

Veja um pouco mais sobre o [`em`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)) em tipografia na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography))

### O "rem":

O `em` tinha um problema intrínseco: quando você definia um tamanho de fonte em `em`s, a referência de tamanho era a do elemento superior, o que causava uma certa confusão, dependendo de como os elementos eram apresentados em relação aos outros.

Para resolver o problema, à partir do *CSS3* foi implementado o `rem`, muito similar ao `em`, mas que toma sempre por base o elemento raíz da página. Assim, a referência vai ser sempre a fonte do `html`, e não do elemento superior.

### O "px":

*Pixel* é a abreviação de *Picture Element*, e se refere aos pontinhos que compõe as imagens na tela, e é a origem da unidade `px`.

As imagens, pela própria natureza, têm suas medidas de largura e altura em `px`, e a área útil da tela e da página do browser também são medidas nativamente em `px`. Esta é a medida usual para especificar `@media` queries.

**Usualmente** os `px` do *CSS* correspondem aos pixels físicos do dispositivo, e esta ainda é a regra na maior parte dos casos.

No entanto, isso não é mais uma certeza absoluta: com as telas de alta definição, e o fato das decisões de mercado serem tomadas por Comitês, e não gente que realmente usa os padrões, em alguns casos o `px` pode não corresponder necessariamente ao *pixel* do dispositivo físico, como nos displays de alta densidade. Veja a questão a seguir:

[Qual o DPI recomendado para imagens utilizadas em websites?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11048/qual-o-dpi-recomendado-para-imagens-utilizadas-em-websites)

E também as [especificações do w3c sobre os "pixels de referência"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#x39) <sup>(en)</sup>.

### A porcentagem (%):

A porcentagem, assim como o `em`, também é relativa, mas em unidades absolutas, proporcional ao elemento em si, e não à fonte diretamente.

Exemplos:

```
.exemplo {
   font-size: 20px;
   line-height: 150%;
}
```

Assim, teremos espaçamento 1,5 entre linhas, como no exemplo anterior, mas usando `%`. Notar que apesar de estarmos usando um elemento cujo tamanho aparentemente depende da fonte, a porcentagem é relativa ao tamanho natural do bloco, e não das letras em si (mas de qualquer forma, corresponde a UMA linha do bloco, no caso de blocos de texto).

```
H1 {
   width: 50%;
}
```

Um cabeçalho com metade do que seria a largura total.

### Qual usar?

Depende da situação. Não tem um "melhor", nem "certo e errado". Depende da intenção desejada. Se você está usando `@media` para fazer layouts para vários dispositivos, e gosta de ter controle preciso sobre o resultado, não há problema nenhum em definir tudo em *pixels*, o que é uma técnica boa para que o resultado seja exatamente o que você espera.

Tem alguns elementos que vão ser usados em parágrafos com diferentes fontes, proporcionalmente? Use o `em`, pois você terá a certeza que o elemento vai ser proporcional ao texto.

O ideal é saber bem as diferenças, pois assim você não fica limitado às "[boas-práticas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/813/70)" e usa a ferramenta certa nos lugares e hora certos, com segurança.

### Veja também:

> [O em e o rem usam as tags html ou body como referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126209/70)

Comment: Não que as "boas-práticas" sejam problemáticas por si só; o problema é segui-las cegamente, sem entender o motivo.

Answer (score 9):

Por que a unidade de medida `em` é relativa em relação ao tamanho da fonte, já o `px` é uma unidade de medida que também é relativa, e seu valor é gerado em relação ao dispositivo (midia) de exibição.

Como é citado [aqui](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/medidascss.php) por Maurício Samy Silva (Maujor):

"O valor é tomado em relação:

```
em: ...ao tamanho da fonte ('font-size') herdada;
px: ...ao dispositivo (midia) de exibição;
```

"([Maujor](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/medidascss.php))

Então é logicamente mais confiável setar o tamanho da fonte, por uma unidade que é abstraída de sua própria medida.

Exemplo: Se eu seto o tamanho da fonte em `12px` para um componente, estou dizendo que para esse componente `1em == 12px`, logo `2em == 24px`, e você também pode utilizar esse valor como ponto flutuante, ex: `1.5em = 18px`.

> Esse [artigo](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) demonstra muito bem o funcionamento, das unidades de medidas para `font-size`, se puder dar uma olha, acredito que irá lhe ajudar a entender melhor cada um deles.

Answer (score 7):

`Em` é uma unidade relativa de medida, ou seja `1em` pode ter tamanhos diferentes dependendo do contexto.

O valor `default` de `1em` é igual ao da `font-size` do pai do elemento.

Ex

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Em</title>
</head>
    <style>
        body{ font-size: 16px; }    
        p.t1{ font-size: 1em; }
        p.t2{ font-size: 1.5em; }           
        p.t3{ font-size: 3em; }
        p.t4{ font-size: 5em; }
    </style>
<body>
<div>
    <p class="t1">Teste 1</p>
    <p class="t2">Teste 2</p>
    <p class="t3">Teste 3</p>
    <p class="t4">Teste 4</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A vantagem é que dessa maneira se mantém a proporção das fontes, se for necessário mudar o tamanho, só se mudaria a em uma única linha.