# Qual é a alternativa moderna aos framesets?

Tags: html, html5

Sei que o frame que costumava carregar algumas páginas em uma só não se utiliza mais, na internet há um vasto conteúdo dizendo que isso é obsoleto.

Mas qual seria a alternativa ideal para esse objetivo? Carregar uma página em um tamanho determinado e outras paginas logo ao lado na mesma pagina principal?

*Código obsoleto?*

```
<frameset border="1" cols="25%,*">
    <frame NAME="coluna1" src="pagina.html" RESIZE target="main">
    <frame NAME="coluna2" src="pagina2.php" RESIZE target="content">
    <noframes>
        <body>
        </body>
    </noframes>
</frameset>
```

Gostaria de exemplos.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### O `iframe`:

Você pode usar o "primo" do `<frame>`, o `<iframe>`, que além de suportado pelo HTML5, ganhou alguns novos atributos.

Com o `iframe`, HTML normal pode ser usado na página, ao mesmo tempo que os `iframe` colocado no `body`. `iframes` podem ser estilizados com CSS para se posicionar e ocupar o tamanho desejado, se comportando como qualquer elemento de bloco.

Assim você pode misturar conteúdo externo com a pagina até mesmo se o JavaScript estiver desligado. Inclusive, com o atributo `sandbox`, pode até bloquear o JS nas páginas carregadas dentro do `iframe`.

```
...
<body>
   <h1>Cabecalho da pagina<h1>
   <p>
      HTML normal pode ser usado na pagina, e o &lt;iframe&gt; colocado
      e estilizado com CSS para posicionar e ocupar o tamanho desejado,
      como qualquer elemento de bloco
   </p>
   <iframe name="coluna1" src="pagina.html" width="300" height="500">
   <iframe name="coluna2" src="pagina2.php" width="300" height="500">
   <p>
      Assim você pode misturar conteudo externo com a pagina ate mesmo se o
      JavaScript estiver desligado.
   </p>
</body>
```

### Atributos do `iframe` em HTML5:

- `src` = URL a ser carregado
- `srcdoc` = Conteúdo HTML
- `name` = contexto usado para `target`
- `sandbox` = `allow-same-origin`, `allow-top-navigation`, `allow-forms`, `allow-scripts`
  define algumas restrições de segurança.
- `seamless` = indica que o iframe deve ser renderizado aparentando ser parte da página
- `width` = Largura em [CSS Pixels](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14217/)
- `height` = Altura em [CSS Pixels](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14217/)
- Além desses, o `iframe` suporta os atributos globais do HTML, como `id`, `class` etc.

Veja mais na [documentação do W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe).

Answer (score 15):

Além das soluções já apresentadas por *@Bacco* e *@Andrey*, pode ser feito com `Ajax` e `object`:

### Através de Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",       
})
.done(function(conteudo) {
    $('#suadiv').html(conteudo)
});
```

Explicando, você faz uma requisição a uma URL e retorna o conteúdo em uma `div`.

### Através de object

```
$("#area").html('<object data="http://www.brasil.gov.br">');
```

Como diz no **w3schools**:

> You can also use the  tag to embed another webpage into your HTML document.

Traduzindo, além de conteúdo multimidia (como video, Java applets, ActiveX, PDF, e Flash), você pode incluir outra página dentro do seu HTML.

**Obs:** como *@Bacco* bem informou, a w3schools não é uma fonte confiável e pode haver informações inconsistentes.

Já na [documentação da mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) diz:

> The HTML `<object>` Element (or HTML Embedded Object Element) represents an external resource, which can be treated as an image, **a nested browsing context**, or a resource to be handled by a plugin.

Visto isso, você pode utilizar a tag `object` para carregar uma página no seu HTML. Eu testei a tag `object` para carregar uma página dentro de outra e funcionou bem no Safari.

De qualquer forma, recomendo utilizar `iframe` sugerido pelo *@Bacco*.

<sup>obs: ambos utilizam `JQuery`, veja em: http://api.jquery.com</sup>

Comment: Acho que "única" é uma palavra um tanto forte para o caso.

Comment: @Renan você tem razão, inclusive adicionei mais uma solução.

Answer (score 12):

Uma alternativa é usar o método `load()` do jQuery para baixar um arquivo e "colar" seu conteúdo em uma `div`.

```
// HTML
<div id="minha_div"></div>

// jQuery
$("#minha_div").load("/");
```

*[Veja no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VZTJf/)*

Substitua `/` pelo endereço do HTML que quer "colar" ali.

*[Veja a documentação](http://api.jquery.com/load/)*

Answer (score 5):

### Exemplo com PHP

Esse exemplo é ótimo, além de ser muito fácil de implementar em seu site, é de fácil manutenção. iframes forçam muito o servidor.

Você terá que criar sua página em PHP, pois irá utilizar o comando **require_once**.

**Primeiramente**, crie sua página em PHP. Ex: **index.php**

Dentro do **index.php**, você poderá colocar o **require_once** em qualquer lugar da página, até mesmo nas *meta-tags*.

Ex:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="pt-BR" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Aqui irá ficar o título da página</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>
  HTML normal pode ser usado na pagina.
</p>
<!-- puxa o código do arquivo conteudo.php como se fosse um frame/iframe, só que ele renderiza a página como se o código dentro de conteudo.php fosse da própria página -->
<?php
require_once "conteudo.php"
?>
<!-- Você pode adicionar quantos, e onde quizer -->
</body>
</html>
```

**Agora** vamos criar o arquivo **conteudo.php**

Dentro dele vamos colocar o que irá aparecer na página anterior que criamos. (*a index.php*)

```
<p>
Isso é um texto, esse mesmo texto irá aparecer na página index.php como se esse texto fosse da própria página.
</p>
<a href="https://google.com"> Isso é um link que vai para o Google </a>
```

Agora, quando você acessar a página **index.php**, irá mostrar o conteúdo dentro de **conteudo.php**.

Essa sem dúvidas é a melhor alternativa, eu só uso assim em meus sites.

**Obs:** O navegador não lê arquivos PHP localmente (ou seja no seu computador). Se você abrir no navegador no pense que se o código não funcionou porque está quebrado, pois **o código está certo**. O problema é que **o navegador não roda PHP localmente**. Veja abaixo:

Para que você possa ver a sua página normal, será necessário que esses arquivos sejam **hospedados** em um servidor, ou você poderá instalar um **WAMP** para que possa rodar PHP no computador. Recomendo o [**XAMPP**](http://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/download.html), sem dúvidas é o melhor. Você poderá até instalar no seu computador alguns CMS's como: wordpress, joomla, drupal, etc..