# Como atualizar um iframe sem dar refresh na página?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, iframe

Estou fazendo um sistema, mais precisamente, um editor de código *HTML* e *CSS* *online*, no qual necessito fazer o envio de dois campos via `POST` para uma página php, que irá processar os dados e salvá-los em um arquivo html de nome aleatório, gerado à cada atualização de página.

Até aí tudo bem, estou fazendo esse envio de dados via `AJAX` para evitar que a página dê *refresh* e o nome do arquivo se altere.

Na mesma página há um `iframe` que faz referência à página html criada, só que, ao enviar os dados via `AJAX` e salvar no arquivo html, eu devo dar um `reload` no `iframe` para atualizar o arquivo ao qual ele faz referência, desta forma:

```
document.getElementById("myIframe").contentWindow.location.reload();
```

O problema está aí, na hora de dar o `reload` no `iframe`, toda a página é atualizada (digo isso, pois o ícone de carregamento aparece como na imagem abaixo.)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que acarreta na geração de um novo nome de arquivo, que, como eu disse, a cada atualização de página um novo nome é gerado, e na mudança do `src` do `iframe`, apontando para um novo arquivo em branco e não para o arquivo que continha o código.

Comment: `window.open(src, id);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom, hoje em dia eu não incentivo o uso de `iframes`, depois de descobri alguns erros que ele pode acarretar em relação a passagem de parâmetros e tudo o mais....

Mas, a um tempo atrás eu encontrei a seguinte solução:

```
function carregaiframe(src, id) {
   window.open(src, id);
}
```

A chamada da função eu faço assim:

```
carregaiframe("nomeSite.php?parametro=" + paramentro,"nomeDoIframe");
```

Toda vez que voce chamar a função, ele irá carregar o `iframe` novamente..

Para esse tipo de necessidade, eu recomendo a utilização de Ajax, em vez de carregar o conteúdo em um `iframe`, voce carrega ele em uma `div`

Da seguinte forma:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: { 
        parametros1: parametro1,
        parametros2: parametro2
        },
    url: "conteudo.php",
    success: function(data) {
        $('#conteudo').html(data);
    }
});
```

Na página `HTML` basta referenciar seu `JS` acrescentar a lib `JQuery` e adicionar a seguinte linha:

```
<div id="conteudo"></div>
```

**Porque é mais aconselhavel trabalhar com `AJAX` do que com `Iframes`?**

- [Aqui se discute a respeito de porque o uso de `Iframes` é
  considerado uma má-pratica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29841/por-que-o-uso-de-frames-e-iframes-%C3%A9-considerado-uma-m%C3%A1-pr%C3%A1tica)
- Um outro problema que eu descobri na
  marra, é que o navegador `Safari` por padrão não trabalha bem com
  `Iframes` quando existem `váriaveis de sessão` envolvidas na jogada.

No navegador `Safari` em especifico... quando utilizamos um `Iframe` o navegador lê o link que deve ser renderizado dentro dele como sendo de outro domínio, por isso ele não troca variáveis de sessão... Para outros navegadores que possuam a mesma lógica, também ocorrera esse mesmo problema.

Comment: O que você aconselharia, mas com a mesma finalidade?

Comment: Então vou modificar meu código aqui, porque com certeza terei problemas por utilizar as variáveis de sessão. Obrigado!