# Qual a melhor prática para integrar conteúdo externo ao meu site?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, html5

Estou desenvolvendo um site em PHP e vou precisar integrar um conteúdo que vai estar em uma página de um site externo. Esta página vai estar com pouca formatação, sem `header` `footer` e `sidebar`, eu vou ter apenas o link desta página.

Nesta página vai ter um produto com seu thumbnail, nome, preço e com link para ver mais detalhes.

Minha dúvida e da melhor maneira de fazer esta integração. Pensei em usar `iframe` mas fico ocioso quanto a responsividade e também ao SEO do site.

Existe uma opção melhor?

Comment: O seu "integrar" é, literalmente, fazer o teu conteúdo aparecer em outro site?

Comment: Vou precisar integrar um conteúdo que vai estar em uma página de um site externo ao meu site.

Comment: Aqui neste link fala bem o que deve fazer.
[Usos do iFrame hoje em dia (Veja a resposta dada como certa)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15151/qual-%C3%A9-a-alternativa-moderna-aos-framesets)

Comment: Mas seria a melhor solução?

Comment: Esse outro site não tem um Webservice?

Comment: @Intruso, o outro site não tem. O que sei é que ele está em Wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe uma *melhor forma*. Tudo depende do quão interligados esses sites estão e do quanto você "confia" nele.

## Usando `iframe`s

O uso de `iframe`s, como descrevi [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30428/227), é perfeitamente válido quando você quer inserir conteúdo que seja independente da página atual, tanto por questões estéticas, desempenho ou segurança.

O problema de usar um `iframe` não é tanto que seja ruim em si mesmo, mas traz vários outros desafios:

- Como dimensionar os *frames* e manter um layout consistente com o restante da página?
- O que fazer com links dentro do frame?
- É necessário interagir com o conteúdo do frame? Neste caso seria necessário definir cabeçalho de acesso de origens diferentes.

Se o conteúdo desse site Wordpress que você quer incluir é algo que ocasionalmente poderia causar problemas de segurança, como injeção de scripts na sua página, o `iframe` ajuda a isolar aquele conteúdo.

Além disso, se o conteúdo varia frequentemente e você não pode construir um *parser*, o `iframe` acaba sendo a alternativa mais segura.

## Obtendo o conteúdo no servidor

### Usando o HTML diretamente

Se, por outro lado, você confia naquele outro site, talvez porque você mesmo é o administrador, você pode fazer como o Ricardo sugeriu na outra resposta.

O seu servidor faz uma requisição para o outro site e recupera o conteúdo a página que você quer inserir. Depois insere esse conteúdo na sua página.

Além da segurança, esta técnica precisa considerar:

- Estilos e a estrutura da outra página. Eles podem não funcionar se houver caminhos relativos ou podem interferir nos estilos e na estrutura da sua página.
- Fazer requisições para outro servidor cada vez que mostrar uma página vai matar sua performance. O ideal seria manter essas informações em *cache*, talvez num banco de dados, por algum tempo e atualizar de tempos em tempos.

### Interpretando as informações

Se o conteúdo segue sempre a mesma estrutura, a técnica mais avançada e flexível consiste em fazer algum código para ler o conteúdo do outro site e extrair somente as informações relevantes de cada produto.

Com essas informações no seu servidor, você mesmo pode tratá-las para evitar que tragam risco à segurança, tal como codificando em HTML ao escrever na página, limitando o tamanho, etc. Depois pode exibi-las no formato que desejar.

A segunda parte da resposta do Ricardo mostra esta alternativa, usando um *parser* de XML. Porém considere que HTML não segue as mesmas regras do XML, então as chances são de que você vai precisar usar alguma biblioteca específica para interpretar o HTML.

Claro, o ideal seria poder recuperar os dados via web services num formato amigável como JSON, mas fazer parse de HTML quebra um galho quando não é possível.

Se você é o administrador do site Wordpress, considere que existem alguns plugins para trabalhar com REST. Se o site usa um plugin para gerenciar produtos, é provável que ele tenha alguma API. Olhe bem a documentação antes de tirar conclusões.

Por último, para reforçar, esta técnica não funciona bem se as informações lidas não tem uma estrutura definida.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função file_get_contents do PHP.
Essa função lê todo o conteúdo de uma URL e retorna para uma string.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php 
    $url = file_get_contents('http://minha_url.com.br');
    var_dump($url);
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

**UPDATE**

Nesse cado você vai precisar manipular os dados externos com DOM.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://minha_url.com.br";

    $html = trim(file_get_contents($url));
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadXML($html);
    $dados = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
    foreach ($dados as $key => $value) {
       print_r($value);
    }
?>
```

Com isso você consegue pegar todas as tags e conteúdos.

Comment: Eu editei minha pergunta para ficar mais claro. Eu preciso que o conteúdo venha em HTML, com imagem, link, título, preço do produto, etc.

Comment: E esta forma seria melhor que o iframe? Como funciona a questão da responsividade e do SEO com esta função?

Comment: Wendell isso é uma questão que você deve avaliar com muito cuidado. Muitos desenvolvedores acreditam que os iframes não são indexados por motores de buscas. Esse conceito esta errado.  Os iframes são indexados sim, porém como ele é um link externo na renderização dos buscadores o link do conteúdo vai para a página daquele conteúdo e não para o frameset master. No caso se você usar a solução acima não vai ter esse problema pois seria como se você manipulasse um objeto com conteúdo comum.

Comment: **Minha opinião** Eu não usaria iframe em um projeto em pleno 2016. Caso a solução acima não te atenda existe um infinito de possibilidades a se explorar. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Na verdade, se você está inserindo no site algo idêntico que está em outro site já é catastrófico para SEO. Se estivesse realmente preocupado com o SEO acho que deveria repensar nisso antes de está preocupado entre obter via cURL (ou outro método como o mostrado pelo Ricardo) ou por iframe....

Comment: @Inkeliz eu estou montando um site onde ele precise apresentar apenas alguns produtos de outro site, o restante do conteúdo deste site será autêntico, por isso me preocupo com o SEO.