# Pra que serve a tag <frameset>?

Tags: html, html5

Estava lendo [este](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/body) tópico na página da Mozilla, e uma parte me chamou a atenção:

> Retorna o elemento `<body>` ou o `<frameset>` do documento atual, ou null se nenhum destes elementos existir.

O link para `<frameset>` estava ausente, então procurei um pouco, mas os sites que eu encontrei me confundiram mais que explicaram.

[Este](https://www.htmlprogressivo.net/2013/12/frameset-frame-tags-Como-usar-frames-em-sites.html), por exemplo, em um determinado trecho, diz:

> Isso quer dizer que não iremos mais utilizar a tag body, [...]

Por que `document.body` pode retornar `<frameset>`? E por que o `<frameset>` substituiria o `<body>`? O que ele é, na prática?

Comment: Essa tag foi depreciada com o html5, ela era utilizada para renderizar um html dentro de outro, a página do Mozilla sem tradução parece estar melhor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset

Comment: @DanielMendes ["depreciada"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178138/o-que-%c3%a9-um-c%c3%b3digo-depreciado#comment368172_178138)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O elemento `<frameset>` é valido no `DTD HTML Frameset` como já expliquei em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/209599/3635

Exemplo de uso:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

Vale notar que as tags e esta maneira de criar páginas está obsoleto:

- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html
- https://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/obsolete.html

Deve ser evitado e uma boa sugestão **nesta resposta**:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15174/3635

---

### O "DTD HTML Frameset"

O DTD ajuda o navegador a determinar o comportamento, é claro que o navegador "tenta" determinar sem o DTD (DOCTYPE Document), então provavelmente em um documento com frameset outras tags seriam ignoradas, a não ser que o navegador seja muito antigo e não suporte frames (mas é falar muito do passado), então se fizer isto por exemplo:

```
<head>
<title>exemplo de iframe</title>
</head>
<frameset cols="20%, 80%">
  <frameset rows="100, 200">
      <frame src="contents_of_frame1.html">
      <frame src="contents_of_frame2.gif">
  </frameset>
  <frame src="contents_of_frame3.html">
  <noframes>
      seu navegador não suporta frames
  </noframes>
</frameset>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log('body', document.body);
});
</script>
```

Se testar vai notar que a tag `<script>` não processa o JavaScript e também não é renderizada e nem aparece no **inspetor de elementos**, agora se colocar dentro do HEAD irá funcionar:

```
<head>
<title>exemplo de iframe</title>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log('body', document.body);
});
</script>
</head>
<frameset cols="20%, 80%">
  <frameset rows="100, 200">
      <frame src="contents_of_frame1.html">
      <frame src="contents_of_frame2.gif">
  </frameset>
  <frame src="contents_of_frame3.html">
  <noframes>
      seu navegador não suporta frames
  </noframes>
</frameset>
```

Então o elemento principal neste tipo de documento é mesmo o frameset, sendo o principal significa que não podem haver elementos no mesmo nível (exceto o `<head>`) pois este é o objetivo do frameset, ser a subdivisão de uma **janela** (*window subdivision*), como descrito em:

```
<![ %HTML.Frameset; [
<!ELEMENT FRAMESET - - ((FRAMESET|FRAME)+ & NOFRAMES?) -- window subdivision-->
<!ATTLIST FRAMESET
  %coreattrs;                          -- id, class, style, title --
  rows        %MultiLengths; #IMPLIED  -- list of lengths,
                                          default: 100% (1 row) --
  cols        %MultiLengths; #IMPLIED  -- list of lengths,
                                          default: 100% (1 col) --
  onload      %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- all the frames have been loaded  -- 
  onunload    %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- all the frames have been removed -- 
  >
]]>
```

Por isto não existe BODY nele, e o uso de `document.body` para obter o `frameset` é mera convenção.

Note que no doctype do HTML4 é indicado isto:

```
<!-- Feature Switch for frameset documents -->
<!ENTITY % HTML.Frameset "IGNORE">
```

Que afirma que o documento (a página) deve mudar para o formato de framesets e somente a tag frameset é indicada e quando não for o caso ele usa esta estrutura indicada:

```
<!--================ Document Structure ==================================-->
<!ENTITY % html.content "HEAD, BODY">
```

O conteudo de HTML **"poderá"** conter o HEAD e o BODY (não sendo obrigado, claro que os browsers também tentam compensar e nem sempre o motor vai seguir "a risca")