# Colocar line-height do mesmo tamanho do font-size

Tags: css

Quando aplico o tamanho de uma fonte através do `font-size`, sempre fico em dúvida se devo utilizar `line-height` também. Para a fonte e linha ter o mesmo tamanho.
Pois, convenhamos, que fica chato acertar `margin` e `padding` se o `line-height` não está de acordo.

Eu me refiro mais a fontes especificas, aquelas que não são padrões do Windows. Onde utilizo o `font-face`.

Vocês fazem algo parecido?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por mais que os browsers tendam a ter um comportamento considerado padrão, a [especificação do `line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) diz que o parâmetro `normal` recomendado é de `1.0` a `1.2`, ou seja, pode variar de browser para browser significativamente.

Em outras palavras, é sempre bom determinar o `line-height` para que a apresentação das suas páginas seja consistente.

O que você pode levar em consideração é que, quando você especifica a fonte usando a sintaxe composta `font`, pode simplificar utilizando apenas uma barra, não precisando de uma diretiva `line-height` explícita em separado:

```
h1 { font: 26px/30px sans-serif }
h2 { font: 20px/20px sans-serif }
p  { font: 12px/1.5 sans-serif }
```

Neste caso, especificamos que a fonte do `<p>` tem 12px de altura, e o `line-height` equivale a um espaçamento 1.5, ou seja, vai resultar em 18px. Já o `<h1>` tem 26px de altura, e 30px de `line-height`, assim como o `<h2>` terá 20px tanto de altura quanto de distância entre uma linha e outra. Assim, não há necessidade da diretiva `line-height` separada em nenhum dos casos.

Interessante notar que o `line-height` é uma das propriedades que aceita um valor numérico sem unidade, assim como fizemos com o `font` acima. Para especificar um espaçamento 2, basta usar desta forma:

```
p  { line-height: 2 }
```

Assim, a linha terá o dobro da altura da fonte.

Leitura complementar:
[Por que é recomendado utilizar a unidade "em" ao invés de "px" para fontes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14217/)