# Etiquetando foto com problema

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, font, drawing

Fiz um código que etiqueta um `jpg`, escrevendo no rodapé da imagem o endereço do site do cliente.

**O Problema:** Algumas fotos o texto esta vindo gigante como se fosse fonte 72px ao invés de fonte 12px

[Link FOTO Correta](http://megacorretor.com.br:802/online/img/bco_img/3/img_imoveis/1186619356ahxhgzwfrf.jpg)

[Link FOTO incorreta](http://megacorretor.com.br:802/online/img/bco_img/3/img_imoveis/1186619856sryviftnfv.jpg)

Veja que ambas as fotos são verticais, porém o mesmo texto "www.sigasoftware.com.br" fica em tamanho diferente.

Ao rodar o debug do VS aparentemente todos os valores estão parecidos, não justificando essa fonte desse tamanho, preciso de alguma dica de como posso tentar encontrar o problema

Segue parte do código da minha classe `manipula_foto.cs`

```
private void EstampaTexto(int _largura, int phHeight, Graphics grPhoto)
{
    Font crFont = null;
    SizeF crSize = new SizeF();

    crFont = new Font("verdana", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
    crSize = grPhoto.MeasureString(_textoetiqueta, crFont);

    //imagem a 5% da altura, debaixo para cima.
    int yPixlesFromBottom = (int)(phHeight * .05);

    // Agora que temos um tamanho de ponto usar a altura das cordas Copyrights
    // para determinar a coordenada y para desenhar a série de fotografia
    float yPosFromBottom = ((phHeight - 10) - (crSize.Height / 2));

    //Determinar a coordenada x calculando o centro da largura da imagem
    float xCenterOfImg = (_largura / 2);

    //definindo posição central do texto
    StringFormat StrFormat = new StringFormat();
    StrFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    // retangulo de fundo
    Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, 255, 255, 255));
    grPhoto.FillRectangle(brush, 0, yPosFromBottom, _largura, 20);

    //Texto Frente
    SolidBrush semiTransBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(153, 255, 255, 255));
    grPhoto.DrawString(_textoetiqueta,                 //string of text
        crFont,                                   //font
        semiTransBrush,                           //Brush
        new PointF(xCenterOfImg, yPosFromBottom),  //Position
        StrFormat);                               //Text alignment
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você está confundindo as medidas. O construtor de `Font` que você está usando espera o tamanho em unidades `em` que é uma medida relativa e não em pontos `px` que é uma medida absoluta. [Veja a documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font.-ctor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_Font__ctor_System_Drawing_FontFamily_System_Single_System_Drawing_FontStyle_).

[Veja mais sobre o assunto em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14217/101).

Tente usar um [construtor diferente que especifica a unidade de pixel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font.-ctor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_Font__ctor_System_Drawing_FontFamily_System_Single_System_Drawing_FontStyle_System_Drawing_GraphicsUnit_). Escolha o [tipo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphicsunit?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) `Pixel`. Não posso lhe dizer que é a solução mais apropriada conforme resposta citada acima, mas é uma forma que pode "resolver" seu problema.

Comment: creio que a minha fonte seja em point (porém new Font aparece family, float size, FontStyle)

Comment: O exemplo que utilizei foi http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kxs7tfz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: E funcionou fazendo esse exemplo?

Comment: ainda não...rs...

Comment: É que agora não tenho como testar `Drawing`, depois eu tento.

Answer (score 3):

Graças a [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36907/129) resolvi, colocando o tipo de unidade de medida utilizado.

```
crFont = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```