# O em e o rem usam as tags html ou body como referência?

Tags: html, css, pixels

Lendo sobre, vi locais dizendo que as medidas **Em** e **Rem** utilizam a tag `html` como referência outros dizendo que é a tag `body`, mas qual realmente é a tag que é utilizada como referência?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### O `rem` toma por base o `html`, se o documento for um HTML

De acordo com o [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths):

> rem unit: Equal to the computed value of font-size on the root element.

Significando:

> unidade rem: Igual o valor computado do tamanho da fonte do elemento raiz.

E, de acordo com a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length):

> rem: This unit represents the font-size of the root element (e.g. the font-size of the  element).

Ou seja,

> rem: Esta unidade representa o tamanho da fonte do elemento raiz (por exemplo, o tamanho da fonte do elemento )

Para entender o motivo do HTML ser mencionado no "por exemplo", temos que lembrar que o CSS pode ser usado com outros tipos de documento.

No caso específico de um documento HTML, a raíz é justamente o `<html>`, que por sua vez contém o `<head>` e o `<body>`, e todos os demais ítens. Sendo assím, a "raiz do documento" é sinônimo para o `<html>` em documentos HTML, portanto o `rem` toma por base o tamanho da fonte do `<html>`.

### O `em` toma por base o valor herdado pela fonte do elemento

Ainda no link da MDN acima, temos:

> em: This unit represents the calculated font-size of the element. If used on the font-size property itself, it represents the inherited font-size of the element.

Ou seja,

> em: Esta unidade representa o tamanho calculado da fonte do elemento. Se usado no próprio tamanho da fonte, é tomado por base seu tamanho herdado.

Simplificando, o que acontece com o `em` basicamente é o seguinte:

Se você especifica um **tamanho de fonte** como sendo `2em`, ela vai ter o dobro do tamanho que teria normalmente, se não especificasse nada. Um exemplo de uso do `em` é esse (mas não se limite a isto, as possibilidades são muito mais que essas):

```css
.reais span {font-size:.6em}
.tamanho1 {font-size:13px}
.tamanho2 {font-size:20px}
.tamanho3 {font-size:30px}
```

```html
<div class="tamanho1 reais"><span>R$</span>29<span>,90</span></div>
<div class="tamanho2 reais"><span>R$</span>29<span>,90</span></div>
<div class="tamanho3 reais"><span>R$</span>29<span>,90</span></div>
```

Note que neste caso, usamos um `em` só para definir a fonte menor do R$ e dos centavos. O `em` será sempre de `.6` da fonte principal, sem que precisemos nos preocupar com o tamanho da linha.

Por outro lado, se você especifica **a medida de um elemento** com `em`, esta medida será relativa à fonte do próprio elemento. Veja o `em` aplicado no tamanho de um ícone, por exemplo:

```css
.icon {
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNhpF.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size:1em 1em;
  padding-left:1.5em;
  line-height:1em;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

.tamanho1 {font-size:13px}
.tamanho2 {font-size:20px}
.tamanho3 {font-size:30px}
```

```html
<div class="tamanho1 icon">Ícone ajustado</div>
<div class="tamanho2 icon">Ícone ajustado</div>
<div class="tamanho3 icon">Ícone ajustado</div>
```

Note que neste caso com uma definição, o ícone se ajusta para o tamanho da linha, acompanhando a fonte. Por usarmos `em` em suas medidas, quem determina o tamanho do ícone é a fonte.

### Veja também:

> [Por que é recomendado utilizar a unidade "em" ao invés de "px" para fontes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14217/70)

Comment: Achei uma das minhas dúvidas, você acha que seria bom eu utilizar as medidas em ou rem além das fontes, como outras tag...a `div` é um exemplo, o tamanho de uma imagem etc...

Comment: O certo mesmo é entender cada uma e usar onde for melhor. Uma coisa é certa: não faz sentido usar rem pra tudo, nem em pra tudo, nem px pra tudo. Você pode "misturar" sem problemas, desde que com a finalidade certa. Um exemplo: aquele caso do preço que eu pus acima, o ideal é porcentagem ou em, nao é vantagem usar rem nem px lá. Por outro lado, um cabeçalho principal pode ser baseado em rem, afinal, é pra acompanhar a página toda. Mas não tem uma regra geral, o fundamental é você entender pra que cada um serve. Qual é melhor, só depende do objetivo que aquele elemento terá no seu design.