# Usando unidade "em" (ou "rem") para layouts responsivos

Tags: css, layout-responsivo

Lendo alguns artigos de CSS sobre layout responsivo consegui entender alguns novos "conceitos", porém algumas aplicações ainda ficaram meio confusas para mim, o que é o caso do uso de `em` (ou `rem`) para criação de *layouts* mais dinâmicos e responsivos.

Não pretendo entrar em detalhes comparativos, como por exemplo, o que é o `px` e sua diferença entre `%`, `em` ou `rem`, mas sim a aplicação destes de modo geral. Também não pretendo entrar em um nível de detalhamento tão grande no caso de `em` ou `rem`, pois apesar de terem algumas diferenças, são detalhes muito pequenos que podem deixar a discussão muito complexa.

---

Indo para a questão propriamente dita agora, eu consegui compreender bem o conceito quando aplicado às fontes. Por padrão o navegador define a fonte inicial como `16px`, então eu deveria usar variações em `rem`, deste modo a fonte se ajusta adequadamente independente da resolução, densidade de pixels, etc...

Mas e quanto a outros elementos ou propriedades? Por exemplo, digamos eu tenha definido `p` da seguinte forma:

```
p {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0 0 24px;
}
```

Ou seria melhor eu definir de acordo com a mesma lógica? Por exemplo:

```
p {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0 0 1.5rem;
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
    etc...
}
```

Quanto a configuração de outros elementos como os que criam o sistema de colunas, sei que ainda seria mais adequado o uso de `%`, mas também notei um uso bem constante de `em` em `@media()` para definição de *break-points*.

Até que ponto seria ideal essa abordagem, utilizando `em` (ou `rem`) ao invés de `px`? Ou quais considerações eu devo levar em conta nessa tomada de decisão, tendo como objetivo a criação de *layouts* dinâmicos e responsivos.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: [O em e o rem usam as tags html ou body como referência?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126222/70)

Comment: Tem esse também: [Por que é recomendado utilizar a unidade “em” ao invés de “px” para fontes?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14217/70)

Comment: @Bacco Esses links tem bons conteúdos, mas é como eu comentei na questão, eu não pretendo tratar as diferenças técnicas entre as unidades. Por exemplo, o primeiro link explica como o em/rem geram os valores e o segundo fica mais específico ao uso com fontes. Minha maior dúvida é quando expandimos o seu uso. Como por exemplo, dentro de media, position, padding, margin, width, etc.. Com foco em responsividade.

Comment: PS: No fim achei melhor evidenciar alguns pontos nesta resposta, até pra deixar ela mais em dia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14217/70 - de qq forma, se não é o que busca, vamos ver se alguém acrescenta algo legal nesta aqui que justifique duas perguntas sobre o tema, com a abordagem que você procura. De imediato, não consigo pensar muito mais o que falar nisso sem ser repetitivo, mas de repente outros usuários tem pontos que não foram considerados nas outras questões, e que não caberiam naquelas postagens.