# Como inserir um recuo de primeira linha com css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Não sei se o nome é recuo mesmo, mas como aplico esse espaço como na imagem abaixo nos meus parágrafos com css? Tem alguma class no bootstrap?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Em CSS puro basta usar o `text-indent`:

```css
.recuo { text-indent:4em }
```

```html
<p class="text-info recuo">
  <!-- o que vale aqui é só a classe "recuo" -->
  Suspendisse nec tincidunt nulla. Aliquam et urna magna.
  Suspendisse et tortor libero. Mauris risus tellus, auctor eu
  placerat at, auctor a lacus. Nunc porta urna vel luctus porta.
  Pellentesque vulputate tortor velit, non sodales sapien dictum at.
</p>
<p class="text-info recuo">
  <!-- "text-info" é só exemplo de como usar mais de uma classe -->
  Mauris cursus, neque vel egestas posuere, felis ligula mollis
  leo, id scelerisque neque dui sed elit. Maecenas in purus sed
  massa semper elementum. Nunc id bibendum dolor, imperdiet blandit
  urna. Vestibulum ultrices sem nisl, et tincidunt tortor imperdiet
  eget. Maecenas faucibus nisl nec mi aliquam pellentesque eget et ex.
  In ut turpis eget dui maximus volutpat id a arcu.
</p>
```

Apesar do Bootstrap não ter uma classe específica para recuo, você pode usar uma classe padrão do Bootstrap e acrescentar uma sua, dentro do mesmo `class` atual, como no exemplo acima.

No exemplo eu coloquei a título de demonstração o `text-info`, (que no nosso exemplo não faz nada), e em seguida o `recuo` do seu CSS próprio, para demonstrar o `text-indent`.

No lugar dos `4em` que especifiquei, pode usar a medida e unidade que for mais conveniente para o seu caso específico, mais detalhes aqui:

- [É recomendado utilizar a unidade "em" ao invés de "px" para fontes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14217/70)

Comment: O recuo nao deveria ser de 4 caracteres?

Comment: @ViniciusPuttiMorais o recuo pode ser na medida que quiser, basta trocar a unidade `em` pela desejada. Lembrando sempre que em fontes proporcionais, como a fonte do exemplo do autor, cada caractere tem uma largura diferente. E isto varia de fonte para fonte também. Normalmente se espera que os parágrafos tenham um recuo fixo, mesmo que você misture fontes e estilos.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize a propriedade `text-indent: 40px`.