# Medidas relativas e Absolutas

Tags: css, front-end

Em quais casos devo usar cada tipo de medidas? Considerando que hoje deve-se desenvolver voltado sempre para o responsivo, como decidir qual tipo vou usar? Ex.: rem, em, ch, px, %...

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14217/por-que-%C3%A9-recomendado-utilizar-a-unidade-em-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-px-para-fontes

Comment: Nesse caso sugiro a leitura desses dois posts: - [Post 1](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/unidades-css-rem-vh-vw-vmin-vmax-ex-ch/)
- [Post 2](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/unidades-de-medidas-css.php)

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, ajudaram bastante!