# Quebra de coluna em tabela

Tags: css, html5, css3, xslt

Preciso criar uma table de itens que vem a partir de um foreach XSLT para HTML, a cada quatro linhas quebrar em uma nova coluna, segue um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

exemplo de código que não quebra por coluna

```
<table>
    <xsl:for-each select="documentoEstoque/epi">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="DsProdutoEpi" /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Comment: Esse não é o papel de uma tabela... tavez fosse melhor utilizar uma `<ol>` ou `<ul>`

Comment: @LeandroAngelo mas utilizando uma ol/ul eu posso quebrar a cada 4 linhas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou te dar uma opção um pouco diferente pq ela não é usando tabela é usando `UL/LI`

Repare que com a regra `height: calc(1.2em * 4);` eu uso como base a altura da própria fonte com unidades `em` (já considerando o `line-height` padrão de 20%), e multiplico por `* 4`, para ter a altura da lista, e com o `flex-direction: column;` e o `flex-wrap: wrap;` eu vou quebrando em colunas uma ao lado da outra.

Veja o exemplo para entender melhor. E pode mudar o tamanho da `font` pq sempre vai quebrar na quarta linha pq a altura é baseada no tamanho da fonte usando `em`

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 32px;
    height: calc(1.2em * 4);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
</ul>
```

---

> Depends on the *user agent*. Desktop browsers (including Firefox) use a default value of roughly `1.2`, depending on the element's `font-family`.

*"Depende do user agent. Navegadores de desktop (incluindo o Firefox) usam um valor padrão de aproximadamente `1.2`, dependendo da `font-family` do elemento."*

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Values

**OBS:** Para mais detalhes sobre a unidade `EM` leia aqui: [Por que é recomendado utilizar a unidade "em" ao invés de "px" para fontes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14217/por-que-%C3%A9-recomendado-utilizar-a-unidade-em-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-px-para-fontes)