# Definir altura e largura da imagem

Tags: php

Tenho esse código PHP, estou fazendo um upload de fotos e salvo elas em uma pasta chamada 'foto' do meu computador, precisava conseguir definir a imagem com largura e altura de 1000 px e 72dpi, além dos 5mb que já consegui fazer.

`

```
        //Pasta onde o arquivo vai ser salvo
        $_UP['pasta'] = 'foto/';

        //Tamanho máximo do arquivo em Bytes
        $_UP['tamanho'] = 1024*1024*100; //5mb

        //Array com a extensões permitidas
        $_UP['extensoes'] = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');

        //Renomeiar
        $_UP['renomeia'] = false;

        //Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
        $_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
        $_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior que o limite do PHP';
        $_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especificado no HTML';
        $_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
        $_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';

        //Verifica se houve algum erro com o upload. Sem sim, exibe a mensagem do erro
        if($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 0){
            die("Não foi possivel fazer o upload, erro: <br />". $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['arquivo']['error']]);
            exit; //Para a execução do script
        }

        //Faz a verificação da extensao do arquivo
        $extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['arquivo']['name'])));
        if(array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes'])=== false){        
            echo "
                <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/Aula/upload_imagem.php'>
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"A imagem não foi cadastrada extesão inválida.\");
                </script>
            ";
        }

        //Faz a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
        else if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['arquivo']['size']){
            echo "
                <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/Aula/upload_imagem.php'>
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Arquivo muito grande.\");
                </script>
            ";
        }

        //O arquivo passou em todas as verificações, hora de tentar move-lo para a pasta foto
        else{
            //Primeiro verifica se deve trocar o nome do arquivo
            if($UP['renomeia'] == true){
                //Cria um nome baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão .jpg
                $nome_final = time().'.jpg';
            }else{
                //mantem o nome original do arquivo
                $nome_final = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
            }
            //Verificar se é possivel mover o arquivo para a pasta escolhida
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta']. $nome_final)){
                //Upload efetuado com sucesso, exibe a mensagem
                $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO usuarios (
                nome_imagem) VALUES('$nome_final')");
                echo "
                    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/Teste/upload_imagem.php'>
                    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"Imagem cadastrada com Sucesso.\");
                    </script>
                ";  
            }else{
                //Upload não efetuado com sucesso, exibe a mensagem
                echo "
                    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=http://localhost/Teste/upload_imagem.php'>
                    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"Imagem não foi cadastrada com Sucesso.\");
                    </script>
                ";
            }
        }`
```

Comment: de uma olhada na ferramenta http://www.plupload.com/ é relativamente fácil de usar, e tem recursos de envios múltiplos, arrastar e soltar, resize etc... depois que conheci nunca mais fiz upload e resize de imagem "na mão"

Comment: Leitura recomendada sobre DPI: [Qual o DPI recomendado para imagens utilizadas em websites?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11048/70)

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma classe pronta chamada wideimage você encontra ela aqui: http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/

*Exemplo de uso:*

```
// Chama o arquivo com a classe WideImage
require('/caminho/WideImage.inc.php');
// Carrega a imagem 
$image = wiImage::load('/caminho/foto.jpg');
// Redimensiona a imagem
$image = $image->resize(400, 300);
// Salva a imagem em um arquivo (novo ou não)
$image->saveToFile('/caminho/nova_foto.jpg');
```