# Como descobrir a densidade (PPI) da imagem?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Já vi várias pessoas com a mesma dúvida, mas não encontrei nada resolvido.

Se você abre uma imagem no GIMP e/ou Photoshop e clica em Redimensionar Imagem é possível descobrir a resolução da imagem e eu quero fazer isto, ou seja, quero descobrir a resolução da imagem com javascript ou jquery ou javascript ou qualquer outra linguagem que faça isto.

Vale informar que se for possível descobrir o tamanho da imagem em cm, in, mm, m ou qualquer unidade de medida que não seja digital (px) já resolve o meu problema, pois posso fazer o [calculo](http://www.tecnotablet.com.br/2016/07/o-que-sao-e-como-calcular-o-ppi-de-uma.html)

Já consegui pegar alguns dados com JavaScript, JQuery e PHP. Segue o código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Image</title>
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
   // PPI do dispositivo de reprodução (Seu monitor)
     var elem = document.createElement('div');
     elem.style.width = '1in';
     document.body.appendChild(elem);
     var ppiScreen = elem.offsetWidth;
     document.body.removeChild(elem);

     $('#result').append('<p>PPI Screen: '+ppiScreen+' PPI</p>');

   // Javascript
     var img = document.getElementById('img');

   var width = img.width;
     var height = img.height;
     diagonal = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width,2)+Math.pow(height,2));
     $('#result').append('<p>JavaScript: width: '+width+'px; height: '+height+'px; diagonal: '+diagonal.toFixed(3)+'.</p>');

   width = img.clientWidth;
     height = img.clientHeight;
     diagonal = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width,2)+Math.pow(height,2));
     $('#result').append('<p>JavaScript: clientWidth: '+width+'px; clientHeight: '+height+'px; diagonal: '+diagonal.toFixed(3)+'.</p>');

   width = img.naturalWidth;
     height = img.naturalHeight;
     diagonal = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width,2)+Math.pow(height,2));
     $('#result').append('<p>JavaScript: naturalWidth: '+width+'px; naturalHeight: '+height+'px; diagonal: '+diagonal.toFixed(3)+'.</p>');

   width = img.offsetWidth;
     height = img.offsetHeight;
     diagonal = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width,2)+Math.pow(height,2));
     $('#result').append('<p>JavaScript: offsetWidth: '+width+'px; offsetHeight: '+height+'px; diagonal: '+diagonal.toFixed(3)+'.</p>');

   width = img.scrollWidth;
     height = img.scrollHeight;
     diagonal = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width,2)+Math.pow(height,2));
     $('#result').append('<p>JavaScript: scrollWidth: '+width+'px; scrollHeight: '+height+'px; diagonal: '+diagonal.toFixed(3)+'.</p>');

     // JQuery
   img = $('#img');

   width = img.width();
     height = img.height();
     diagonal = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width,2)+Math.pow(height,2));
     $('#result').append('<p>jQuery: width(): '+width+'px; height(): '+height+'px; diagonal: '+diagonal.toFixed(3)+'.</p>');

   width = img.innerWidth();
     height = img.innerHeight();
     diagonal = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width,2)+Math.pow(height,2));
     $('#result').append('<p>jQuery: innerWidth(): '+width+'px; innerHeight(): '+height+'px; diagonal: '+diagonal.toFixed(3)+'.</p>');

   width = img.outerWidth();
     height = img.outerHeight();
     diagonal = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(width,2)+Math.pow(height,2));
     $('#result').append('<p>jQuery: outerWidth(): '+width+'px; outerHeight(): '+height+'px; diagonal: '+diagonal.toFixed(3)+'.</p>');

  });

 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <body>
  <div id='result'></div>

  <?php
   // PHP
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("https://orig00.deviantart.net/f4bf/f/2008/294/f/6/female1_stock_300dpi_47x31cmm_by_sorcererstock.jpg");
   var_dump($width, $height, $type, $attr);
   ?>

   <img id="img" src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/f4bf/f/2008/294/f/6/female1_stock_300dpi_47x31cmm_by_sorcererstock.jpg" style='width:20%;height:20%;'>
   <p>Width: 47,794; Height: 31,801; DPI: 300.</p>

 </body>
</body>
</html>
```

Eaw? Consegue me ajudar?

---

Consigo pegar PPI de algumas imagens com o seguinte código:

```
$filename = "https://orig00.deviantart.net/f4bf/f/2008/294/f/6/female1_stock_300dpi_47x31cmm_by_sorcererstock.jpg";
$image = new Imagick($filename);
$geo=$image->getImageResolution();
echo $geo['x'].'<br>';
echo $geo['y'];
```

De acordo com a introdução do [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.imagick.php) daria para utilizar com variety of formats (over 100) including  DPX, EXR, GIF, JPEG, JPEG-2000, PDF, PhotoCD, PNG, Postscript, SVG, and TIFF.

---

Uma outra maneira que as vezes funciona é de pegar o PPI pelo hexadecimal:

```
$a = fopen($filename,'r');
$string = fread($a,20);
var_dump(bin2hex($string));
$data = bin2hex(substr($string,14,4));
echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';
```

---

Com esta imagem por exemplo http://edumuch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Leverage-Your-Linux-Skills.png o resultado não vai dar certo em nenhuma das duas configurações acima.

---

Realmente só preciso saber o PPI da imagem e preciso de algo que funcione sempre.

Comment: Nem sempre a imagem tem PPI nos metadados. Não pode confundir a resolução da tela (cujo tamanho real geralmente só se consegue com EDID) com a intenção original do autor. Por exemplo, TIFF tem PPI nos metadados, PNG pode ter e pode não ter, JPG não tem PPI nativo. Seria melhor você explicar o que quer obter com o código (o problema real) em vez da maneira que está buscando a solução..

Comment: Assunto relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11048/70 - notar que se quiser um tamanho para impressão, você pode simplesmente usar medidas físicas no CSS, em vez de pixels.

Comment: Eu quero obter a resolução da imagem em PPI! E não é para impressão.

Comment: Se não é para meio físico, realmente PPI não tem muito uso prático. PPI não muda nada na exibição na tela. Uma imagem de 1000px pode ter 10PPI ou 100000PPI que dá na mesma em meio digital. Provavelmente se você disser o que pretende fazer com a informação, talvez a comunidade consiga ajudar melhor (ou ao menos entender qual o problema específico).

Comment: Por exemplo: a imagem do seu link do código só tem 305PPI quando for usada exatamente com 47x31cm. Se diminuir o tamanho da impressão, os PPIs sobem, e vice versa. O cálculo é simples: 5645 / 47 * 2.54

Comment: Como você chegou nas medidas 47 cm x 31 cm?

Comment: 5645 pixels / 305 ppi = 18,50... polegadas. 18,50... polegadas * 2,54 = 47 cm (notar que arredondei o 18,50 pra postar aqui só por uma questão de conveniência) - Basicamente você divide os pixels pelos PPIs desejados para obter o tamanho da saída. Ou divide pela saída desejada, e obtem os PPIs para aquela saída.

Comment: Legal a sua conta, mas você está utilizando o PPI e de acordo com o problema que eu descrevi é exatamente esta variável que eu não tenho.

Comment: Bom, talvez relendo um pouco você entenda que essa "variável" é exatamente o que eu comentei. Ela normalmente não existe em lugar nenhum. Quando existe, é uma "sugestão" do autor da imagem (como num TIFF ou PNG), e não uma medida real. Tanto que esse conceito comumente nem faz parte de imagens JPG, que só armazenam a medida em pixels (que é a única medida real de uma imagem digital rasterizada). Basicamente você pode escolher quantos PPI quer, e o resultado é o tamanho de saída. Ou simplesmente escolhe o tamanho de saída, e o PPI é o resultado da conta.

Comment: Agora, se quiser a medida sugerida em PPIs dos formatos que suportam esta informação, precisa ver caso a caso. PNG armazena os PPIs de uma maneira (e é opcional). TIFF armazena de outra maneira. JPG não armazena. Cada formato usa uma "codificação" diferente.